# Telerik MVC grid, unable to make a dropdownlist on Ajax editing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I'm trying to implement a Telerik MVC grid with Ajax Editing. Basically, it's a class of groups, and every group belongs to an organisation, and I need to show on the edit mode a dropdownlist with the possible organisations to choose.

I've followed the tutorials and this forum but I cannot make it work.

This is my code:

Model:

```
Partial Public Class hdmtGROUP

    <ScaffoldColumn(False)>
    Public Property gID As Integer

    Public Property gORG As Integer

    'Dropdownlist.
    <UIHint("_OrgDropDownListPartial"), Required()>
    Public Property Organisation As String

    <DisplayName("Name")>
    <Required(ErrorMessage:="A {0} is required.")>
    <StringLength(120, ErrorMessage:="{0} is too long.")>
    Public Property gNAME As String

    <DisplayName("Description")>
    <Required(ErrorMessage:="A {0} is required.")>
    <StringLength(2000, ErrorMessage:="{0} is too long.")>
    Public Property gDESC As String

    Private _hdmtORG As hdmtORG
    Public Overridable Property hdmtORG As hdmtORG
        Friend Get
            Return _hdmtORG
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As hdmtORG)
            _hdmtORG = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

Partial Public Class Organisation
    Public Id As Integer
    Public Name As String
End Class
```

My controller:

```
    Public Class GroupController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    Private unitOfWork As UnitOfWork = New UnitOfWork()

    Function Index() As ViewResult
        PopulateOrgsDropDownList()
        Return View(Me.unitOfWork.GroupRepository.Get())
    End Function

    <GridAction()>
    Public Function AjaxSelect() As ActionResult
        Return View(New GridModel(Me.unitOfWork.GroupRepository.Get()))
    End Function

    Private Sub PopulateOrgsDropDownList(Optional selectedOrg As Object = Nothing)
        ViewData("orgs") = Me.unitOfWork.OrgRepository.Get() _
                            .Select(Function(o) New With {.Id = o.orgID, .Name   =o.orgNAME}) _
                            .OrderBy(Function(o) o.Name)
    End Sub
```

My view:

```
'declare the grid and enable features
Dim grid = Html.Telerik().Grid(Model) _
                    .Name("Grid") _
                    .DataKeys(Function(k) k.Add(Function(g) g.gID)) _
                    .Pageable() _
                    .Sortable() _
                    .Filterable() _
                    .ToolBar(Function(t) t.Insert()) _
                    .DataBinding(Function(dataBind) dataBind.Ajax() _
                                    .Select("AjaxSelect", "Group") _
                                    .Insert("Create", "Group") _
                                    .Update("Edit", "Group") _
                                    .Delete("Delete", "Group"))
'Add grid columns
grid.Columns(Function(columns) columns.Bound(Function(g) g.gNAME).Width(200))
grid.Columns(Function(columns) columns.Bound(Function(g) g.gDESC).Width(200))
grid.Columns(Function(columns) columns.Bound(Function(g) g.Organisation).Width(200))
grid.Columns(Function(columns) columns.Command(Function(s) {s.Edit().ButtonType(GridButtonType.BareImage), s.Delete.ButtonType(GridButtonType.BareImage)}).Width(65))
'Render the grid
grid.Render()  
function onEdit(e) {
    $(e.form).find('#Organisation').data('tDropDownList').select(function (dataItem) {
        return dataItem.Text == e.dataItem['Organisation'];
    });
}
```

And the partial view:

```
@imports System.Collections
@imports Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI
@(Html.Telerik().DropDownList() _
      .Name("Organisation") _
      .BindTo(New SelectList(DirectCast(ViewData("orgs"), IEnumerable), "Id", "Name")))
@
```

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You made wrong by creating _OrgDropDownListPartial as partial view. You should put your all UiHint attributed codes in **Views\Shared\EditorTemplates** folder.

In your case , you should move all your _OrgDropDownListPartial partial view codes into a Views\Shared\EditorTemplates_OrgDropDownListPartial.ascx file

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, thanks a lot! It works now, but there's still a problem: the dropdownlist appears well when pressing the edit button, and it updates the values in the databse, but I can't populate the Organisation column with the value of the field. I've created a partial class in the model but it doesn't work, do you know what's the problem? (I have updated the code with the last attempt)

Comment: Do you mean that when you press the "edit" button, the related organisation doesn't select in the DropDownList? Indeed you don't need to do anything!
PAY ATTENTION! : If your combobox is bound to a list of items (with key/value pair like (OrgId,OrganizationName) ), your model should keep the OrgId field and not the OrganizationName! After that, the telerik DropDownList automatically select the related item when you change to edit mode

Comment: I mean that when I load the grid, the column about Organisation appears with no information. And when I press the Edit button, the dropdown list appears but not on the related Organisation, it appears just the dropdown list. As I said before, I added my Public Property Organisation As String and I made it a partial class with Id and Name (see the model) but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you're talking about but I guess I'm missing something.

The Organisation class I need to load in the column is this:

```
Partial Public Class hdmtORG

    Public Property orgID As Integer
    Public Property orgNAME As String

    Private _hdmtGROUPs As ICollection(Of hdmtGROUP) = New HashSet(Of hdmtGROUP)
    Public Overridable Property hdmtGROUPs As ICollection(Of hdmtGROUP)
        Friend Get
            Return _hdmtGROUPs
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As ICollection(Of hdmtGROUP))
            _hdmtGROUPs = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

I'm following this example, with a Unit of Work and Generic Repository, for my model:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

The point is that I understand I'm not loading properly my Organisations (hdmtORG) to show them on my groups (hdmtGROUP) Grid column. I had to make private my property hdmtORG in hdmtGROUP to avoid the circular reference error. When I make the query, if I add the parameter "including hdmtORG", the ORGs are loaded in my model, I can see it in the view as Model(0).hdmtORG.orgNAME. But there's no way to show them on the grid.Columns. When I try something like this

`grid.Columns(Function(columns) columns.Bound(Function(g) g.hdmtORG.orgNAME))`

I cannot access because GET of hdmtORG is not accesible and it asks me for a string value.